# Using mmap with /dev/mem - Is it okay to use reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm using `mmap` with `/dev/mem`. I've seen [examples](https://github.com/digibird1/Cyclone-V-SoC-system_Base/blob/master/SoC_Memory_2/main.c#L176) in C use the following pattern:

```
#define OFFSET = ...;
int fd = 0;
void* base;

fd = open("/dev/mem", ...);

base = mmap(..., fd, ...);

// Below is line of interest.
*((uint32_t*)(base + OFFSET)) = 23;
```

**First question - What is happening here?**

It looks like we are adding an offset value to a `void*`, then casting it to `uint32_t*` and then assigning a number to it. Why can't we just declare `base` as `uint32_t*`? Why cast it just before assigning it?

**Second question - How would I do this in C++?**

The following works from bits and pieces on the net. But it's basically me trying whack-a-mole with `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast` and seeing which one gives me the right result and doesn't throw errors or warnings. Also replaced `void*` with `uint8_t*` to prevent compiler warning me of arithmetic on `void` pointer. I don't know why it works or if it's even the right way to do it. Help me not shoot myself in the foot?

```
#define OFFSET = ...;
int fd = 0;
uint8_t* base;

fd = open("/dev/mem", ...);

base = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mmap(..., fd, ...));

*(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(base + OFFSET)) = 23;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base + OFFSET` is a `gcc` extension where pointer arithmetic works on `void *`. "Why can't we just declare base as `uint32_t*`?" Because the arithmetic would come out wrong. `void *` arithmetic is in bytes.

There seems to be some confusion as to the meaning of arithmetic in bytes. `OFFSET` is the number of bytes (not 32 bit integers) from base where the value 23 needs to go; so casting to `uint32_t` first would move four times as far. This kind of code is typical of code that writes to heterogeneous data-structures directly rather than using a struct. There's pros and cons of declaring a struct vs. writing the accesses out directly. In the ancient days they usually declared a struct, but the pendulum has swung back because of alignment issues. It's easier to ensure the compiler doesn't hose the struct definition by inserting padding by writing it out longhand.

```
base = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mmap(..., fd, ...));
*(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(base + OFFSET)) = 23;
```

This is indeed what you'd have to do to say it in standard C++; though for code like this people tend to use C style casts in C++ (not going to debate it; just pointing it out).

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain more about the gcc extension or share a link for me to read more? It isn't included in `g++`? Also, what do you mean when you say `void*` arithmetic is in bytes? Aren't all pointers the same size in a given arch?

Comment: Found a [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) to the `void*` arithmetic. So effectively we just need a pointer to byte sized object?

Comment: Ah I think I understand now - so we're basically scrolling through the memory location one byte at a time. But when we reach the memory location we're concerned with, we want to write 4 bytes and hence we are casting it to `uint32_t`? And this is easier than writing one byte at a time because the compiler will take care of the endianness for us?

Comment: note casting from `void*` can be done with `static_cast`

Comment: @Mgetz - You're right, but looks like casting from `uint8_t*` to `uint32_t*` only works with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @PlastyGrove correct as it's not a safe cast. FWIW C++ assumes that a person writing a system specific allocator will deal with things like alignment etc. themselves. So if I were to write a `mmap_allocator<T>` it would ensure that any memory returned by `allocate` would be properly aligned etc. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: @Mgetz - Yup, that makes sense, thank you! :)